# STM32F4 not pushing/popping floating point registers

Tags: c, assembly, arm, keil, compiler-bug

I have a code

```
const float previousTemperature = getTemperature();
someNestedFunction();
someOtherActions();
setTemperature(previousTemperature);
```

My problem is that in `someNestedFunction();` `previousTemperature` gets modified. I have looked at the disassembly and I can't find any instructions that would push or pop the register in which `previousTemperature` is stored, before calling.

I have checked ARM [documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0298a/DAFGGBJD.html) and it states:

> The other registers in the FPU, that is, S0-S15 and FPSCR, are always
>   saved automatically.

My variable is stored in S18, so how can I make sure it will be saved and restored correctly? I would like to find a solution that would avoid messing with Asm.

My processor is STM32F437ZGT and I use Keil uVision 5 compiler.

**EDIT:**

So far I have tried to comment the contents of `someNestedFunction()` to find out what exactly is modifying the register in which my variable is. It turns out, that it is touched by a call to

```
snprintf(msg, 10, "%4.2f", value/100.0f);
```

Tomorrow I will check if anything is corrupting the stack.

**Edit2:**

The register in which `previousTemperature` resided, was pushed/popped after all. I haven't noticed that, because in dissasebly D9 register was used, which shadows S18 and S19. Also, it seems that `value` in `snprintf(msg, 10, "%4.2f", value/100.0f);` was some uninitialized garbage. After it was corrected, `previousTemperature` stays the same all the time. However, why this is happening is a mystery for me, and I'm afraid that the true problem is still out there, I just can't observe any symptoms.

Comment: `previosTemperature` isn't the same variable name as the constant: note the typo: (previos vs. previous).  I assume that's just an error in copying your code into the question, though.  If you aren't using any inline asm, then it sounds like a compiler bug unless you're somehow lying to the compiler.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, that was a typo. I don't use inline asm anywhere.

Comment: If it needs to survive a function call, the compiler should be putting it in a register that the ABI says is call-preserved.  I haven't used Keil tools, but it's not normal to have to do anything special to get plain C semantics (like variables keeping their values!) to work properly.

Comment: Are you sure the variable is kept in a register? Couldn't it be saved on the stack? In this case you might have a bug that corrupts the stack in ``someNestedFunction``. Try commenting bits of it until you narrow the problem down to the culprit (this of course assumes that commenting out the call to ``someNestedFunction`` "solves" the problem in the first place)

Comment: does replace of `const` with `volatile` changes the situation?

Comment: Per [the ABI](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/IHI0042F_aapcs.pdf), s16-s31 are callee-saved, so one of the intervening functions (or possibly an interrupt handler) is either corrupting the stack or touching FP registers behind the compiler's back. You want to debug and fix _that_, not bodge around it in this function. Besides, the automatic stacking of caller-saved registers on exception entry, which is what you've referred to, really doesn't have anything to do with anything here.

Comment: @Serge Even if that helps, that wouldn't cure the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Notlikethat What do you mean by _touching FP registers behind the compiler's back_?

Comment: @mactro yes, but it may help to identify the source of the problem

Comment: If the compiler generates code which touches a callee-saved register, it will also generate the necessary prologue/epilogue to preserve and restore the previous value. If any improper inline (or out of line) assembly or other trickery results in the compiler not emitting that prologue/epilogue code (because it's not aware of the registers being touched), or control flow somehow bypassing it, then all bets are off.

Answer (score -1):

Nice detective work to find that the reg is getting saved as D9.

What kind of uninitialized garbage in snprintf are you talking about?  Did you pass a bogus pointer?  If so, then `snprintf` probably overwrote the location on the stack where your variable was being saved/restored to/from, because the buf pointer it received told it to do that.

Corrupting data on the stack typically leads to bad return addresses (causing segfaults) or bad data in variables that are supposed to survive function calls.

---

update: if it was just the float that was uninitialized, that doesn't explain anything.

**Suggestion**: set breakpoints at the outer-most place where D9 is saved and restored.  Set a watchpoint on the stack address where it's saved, so you can detect when the memory is overwritten while it still holds the saved value of your variable.

Comment: The call looks like: 
    `char msg[10];
    snprintf(msg, 10, "%4.2f", value/100.0f);`, where value was a float which wasn't initialized.

Comment: @mactro: Hmm, reading an uninitialized  float doesn't explain it. :/  snprintf should still just print NaN or some decimal digits into `msg`, and does always null-terminate the string.  (Unlike strncpy).